# Separate one module from JSF application

Tags: rest, jsf, jakarta-ee, architecture, microservices

We have big JSF monolithic application. We want to change the architecture of this application. Currently, my goal - change one module in our application. I need to move the logic from one module to another application which will be implemented on another stack of technologies (it will be rest-service with some js-framework on frontend).

The application should work in the same way. We should have the link to the page as it was earlier but this page should be rendered by another service. We should have the same session between these 2 applications. The user should be able to go throw the pages without an additional step of authentification.

We are planning to move also other modules, not only this one. I need a help. Do you have any thoughts how it should be implemented? any examples?

Comment: _"some js-framework on frontend"_ ;-)... 'some'.... WebFragments is the way to go. Independend of JSF... Works great

Comment: @Kukeltje, it should be another application. Some js-framework - react or angular.

Comment: I'm not sure to good understand You, IMO separate business layer from View is core, whatever idea of 'frontend' win

Comment: In different words: do You mean cut modules vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do this for me is using a SSO service like [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/), as your Identity Provider. That involves porting your authentication logic to it and decouple it from your monolith. But once you rely on it as your IdP, you only share tokens between your applications and IdP. Keycloak has many adapters, for Java, Javascript, NodeJs clients.. and so on. That has the huge advantage that you can keep decoupling logic from your monolith and you don't even need new modules to be written in Java. You could even integrate it with services not written by you, it's enough for them to have Open Id Connect or SAML integrations.

KC supports both SAML and OIDC Auth protocols. With OIDC (the way to go with brand new applications), the adapter located in each of the apps checks wether the user has a valid web session or not. If not, it gets redirected to KC login page. The result of a valid login is a code which you can use to obtain an access token (a valid token to obtain resources from your app). Apart from that, the adapter ties that access token to a browser web session, which is stored in KC too. So if you try to access the other web page, the adapter checks for your web session, which finds to be valid.

You can use it to access your apps from a mobile device too, taking care of the access token management/renewal in the mobile app yourself.

[image]

**See also:**

- [The OpenId Connect protocol](http://openid.net/connect/)

Comment: hear hear  finally someone who 'gets it' cheers. Upvoted after (initially) reading only the first few sentences.